# Change Sculpt Tools Layout

Tags: tools

Simple question.  I have done it before but don't remember how how to change the Sculpt Tool layout between one and two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the edge of the column of tool icons to the right.

Comment: That just makes the column wider until it covers half the screen.

Comment: What Blender version are you using? It works fine here in 2.83.5. You get the double-ended arrow, drag to the right, and it changes to 2-column.

Comment: I've just been experimenting. If you pull the edge slowly to the right, it changes to two column, but if you continue to drag right it then goes back to single column with text descriptions and if you drag fast enough it will go straight to descriptive text.. So try dragging more slowly!

Comment: I am running version 2.83.1.  I have been able to change it in the past but right now the single column of controls in sculpt mode is so long it is running off the bottom of the screen so I can not see them all at once.

Comment: AH HA. The format is dependent on how I enter Sculpt mode. If Enter using the button in the top bar it is showing the controls as a double column. Is I enter using the drop down above the controls it shows a single column.

Comment: It works the same either way here.